# How to make all elements in groups of svg change color onclick (js)

Tags: javascript, function, svg, colors, setattribute

I want to change the fill (onclick) of all elements in a group from a svg file. At the moment, I use javascript to set an attribute to an id. This seems to only change one of the elements.

I have tried inline of svg using onclick. it didn´t seem to work. So i started with javascript. Now, it fills only one trianlge, whilst I set the function to call from the group.

```js
function callred(){
  document.getElementById('btn1').setAttribute('fill', '#ff00ff');
}
```

```css
#svg-object{
    
        height: 100vh;    
        width: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        border: 15px antiquewhite;
        position: absolute;
    
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg id="svg-object" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="800px" height="754px" viewBox="0 0 800 754" enable-background="new 0 0 800 754" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="btn1" onclick="callred()">
 <polygon fill="#FF0013" points="366.699,131 410,56 453.301,131  "/>
 <polygon fill="#07FF00" points="323.699,656 367,581 410.301,656  "/>
 <polygon fill="#0000FF" points="409.699,656 453,581 496.301,656  "/>
 <polygon points="366.699,581 410,656 453.301,581  "/>
</g>


</svg>
```

I expect all elements in the group to change to another color when clicked on any element of the group and for them to stay this color.

Comment: Do you have access to jQuery?

Comment: I could although I´m not there yet.. I haven´t learned anything about it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst what you are doing is correct, you are trying to apply a fill to the group and not the elements within it - simply looping through the elements within the clicked svg will allow you to fill them all the same colour. I used a `for` loop for browser support.

Also worth noting that after the click it won't show until after you've moved your mouse off the element, because despite you setting a fill there is still a `hover` property set in your css.

```js
function callred(){
    const children = document.getElementById('btn1').children;
  for(let i = 0; i < children.length; i++ ){
    children[i].setAttribute('fill','#ff00ff');
  }
}
```

```css
g:hover > polygon{
    fill: yellow;
}
b:hover > polygon{
    fill: yellow;
}

#svg-object{
    
        height: 100vh;    
        width: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        border: 15px antiquewhite;
        position: absolute;
    
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg-object" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="800px" height="754px" viewBox="0 0 800 754" enable-background="new 0 0 800 754" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="btn1" onclick="callred()">
 <polygon fill="#FF0013" points="366.699,131 410,56 453.301,131  "/>
 <polygon fill="#07FF00" points="323.699,656 367,581 410.301,656  "/>
 <polygon fill="#0000FF" points="409.699,656 453,581 496.301,656  "/>
 <polygon points="366.699,581 410,656 453.301,581  "/>
</g>


</svg>
```

Comment: great! Wouldn't have thought of that! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This works

```js
function callred() {

 [...document.getElementById('btn1').querySelectorAll('*')].forEach((e) => {
    e.setAttribute('fill', '#ff00ff');
  });
}
```

```css
#svg-object{
    
        height: 100vh;    
        width: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        border: 15px antiquewhite;
        position: absolute;
    
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg id="svg-object" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="800px" height="754px" viewBox="0 0 800 754" enable-background="new 0 0 800 754" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="btn1" onclick="callred()">
 <polygon fill="#FF0013" points="366.699,131 410,56 453.301,131  "/>
 <polygon fill="#07FF00" points="323.699,656 367,581 410.301,656  "/>
 <polygon fill="#0000FF" points="409.699,656 453,581 496.301,656  "/>
 <polygon points="366.699,581 410,656 453.301,581  "/>
</g>


</svg>
```

not sure it's a good answer

You can also use CSS

```js
function callred() {
 document.getElementById('btn1').classList.toggle("forcecolor");
}
```

```css
.forcecolor * {
  fill: blue;
}

#svg-object{
    
        height: 100vh;    
        width: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        border: 15px antiquewhite;
        position: absolute;
    
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg id="svg-object" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="800px" height="754px" viewBox="0 0 800 754" enable-background="new 0 0 800 754" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="btn1" onclick="callred()">
 <polygon fill="#FF0013" points="366.699,131 410,56 453.301,131  "/>
 <polygon fill="#07FF00" points="323.699,656 367,581 410.301,656  "/>
 <polygon fill="#0000FF" points="409.699,656 453,581 496.301,656  "/>
 <polygon points="366.699,581 410,656 453.301,581  "/>
</g>


</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementsByTagName('polygon')` to get all the polygons and then loop over them, setting the fill of each one:

```js
function callred(){
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('polygon')
  for (var i=0; i < els.length; i++) {
      els[i].setAttribute('fill', '#ff00ff');
  }
}
```

```css
#svg-object{
    
        height: 100vh;    
        width: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        border: 15px antiquewhite;
        position: absolute;
    
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg id="svg-object" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="800px" height="754px" viewBox="0 0 800 754" enable-background="new 0 0 800 754" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="btn1" onclick="callred()">
 <polygon fill="#FF0013" points="366.699,131 410,56 453.301,131  "/>
 <polygon fill="#07FF00" points="323.699,656 367,581 410.301,656  "/>
 <polygon fill="#0000FF" points="409.699,656 453,581 496.301,656  "/>
 <polygon points="366.699,581 410,656 453.301,581  "/>
</g>


</svg>
```

Comment: Aaron McGuire's answer is better

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd probably just toggle a css class to hit the children;

```js
function callred(){
   document.getElementById("btn1").classList.toggle("new-style");
}
```

```css
#svg-object{
    
        height: 100vh;    
        width: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        border: 15px antiquewhite;
        position: absolute;
    
}

.new-style polygon {
  fill: red!important;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg id="svg-object" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="800px" height="754px" viewBox="0 0 800 754" enable-background="new 0 0 800 754" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="btn1" onclick="callred()">
 <polygon fill="#FF0013" points="366.699,131 410,56 453.301,131  "/>
 <polygon fill="#07FF00" points="323.699,656 367,581 410.301,656  "/>
 <polygon fill="#0000FF" points="409.699,656 453,581 496.301,656  "/>
 <polygon points="366.699,581 410,656 453.301,581  "/>
</g>


</svg>
```